# Reducing a sequence into a shorter sequence while calling a function on each adjacent element

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

I've got a function that looks at two of these objects, does some mystery logic, and returns either one of them, or both (as a sequence).

I've got a sequence of these objects `[o1 o2 o3 o4 ...]`, and I want to return a result of processing it like this:

- call the mystery function on o1 and o2
- keep the `butlast` of what you've got so far
- take the `last` of the result of the previous mystery function, and call the mystery function on it, and o3
- keep the `butlast` of what you've got so far
- take the `last` of the result of the previous mystery function, and call the mystery function on it, and o4
- keep the `butlast` of what you've got so far
- take the `last` of the result of the previous mystery function, and call the mystery function on it, and oN
- ....

Here's what I've got so far:

```
; the % here is the input sequence
#(reduce update-algorithm [(first %)] (rest %))

(defn update-algorithm
  [input-vector o2]
  (apply conj (pop input-vector)
    (mystery-function (peek input-vector) o2)))
```

What's an idiomatic way of writing this?  I don't like the way that this looks.  I think the `apply conj` is a little hard to read and so is the `[(first %)] (rest %)` on the first line.

Comment: I take it that the `input-vector` parameter corresponds to `consent-vector` in the body?

Comment: @MichałMarczyk typo :) Fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`into` would be a better choice than `apply conj`.

I think `[(first %)] (rest %)` is just fine though. Probably the shortest way to write this and it makes it completely clear what the seed of the reduction and the sequence being reduced are.

Also, `reduce` is a perfect match to the task at hand, not only in the sense that it works, but also in the sense that the task *is* a reduction / fold. Similarly `pop` and `peek` do exactly the thing specified in the sense that it is their purpose to "keep the `butlast`" and "take the `last`" of what's been accumulated (in a vector). With the `into` change, the code basically tells the same story the spec does, and in fewer words to boot.

So, nope, no way to improve this, sorry. ;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I'm glad you could understand what I was trying to do, because I had a lot of trouble describing it.